# rails routing error only when ajax used

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

My vote link generally works except when the link is rendered through a ajax partial. When rendered through the JavaScript partial I get a routing error which is visible in firebug and no error otherwise.

Without firebug I know there is an error because the manufacturer is not added when I try to add a new manufacturer. If I refresh the page manually the link and new manufacturer are present and voting works.

So basically using ajax breaks the vote link.

rake routes:

```
vote_car_manufacturer POST   /cars/:car_id/manufacturers/:id/vote(.:format)                manufacturers#vote
```

view:

```
<%= link_to '+', vote_car_manufacturer _path(car_id: @car.id, manufacturer_id: manufacturer.id, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
```

firebug:

```
No route matches {:action=>"vote", :controller=>"manufacturers", :car_id=>1, :manufacturer_id=>29, :type=>"up"}
```

Do I have to implement the vote link differently when using ajax?

**UPDATE**

Got it semi-working through trial and error. Changed:

```
<%= link_to '+', vote_car_manufacturer _path(car_id: @car.id, manufacturer_id: manufacturer.id, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
```

to:

```
<%= link_to '+', vote_car_manufacturer _path(@car.id, manufacturer.id, "up"), :method => :post %>
```

Now It says cannot find manufacturer without an ID so I am still debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about ajax call, but

```
:remote => true
```

is not in **link_to**,
as specified in the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Comment: The ajax call renders a partial (that includes the links). The links themselves are not ajax links.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite trivial. First run rake routes and make sure you provide the parameters that the route requests in the right format.

In my case the parameters should have been vote_car_manufacturer _path(@car.id, id: manufacturer, type: "up")

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem solved.  Don't forget to give yourself the checkmark.